# Block Firewall IP and UDP Port not effected on Centos 7

Tags: udp, centos7, block, firewalld

I have blocked all these method in my firewalld public zone but yet any of these not work.
I wanted to block a UDP port on Cenots 7. these are the rules i tried, also public zone is my only active zone.

```sh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=123.123.123.123 port port=1212 protocol=udp drop'

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 port port=1212 protocol=udp drop'

firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=123.123.123.123 port port=1212 protocol=udp reject'
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of this...?